# add custom title after page break

Tags: java, ms-word, jaxb, docx, docx4j

i am using docx4j library and using templating to genearte report from my application.
i have following requirement,

When a page break comes between a paragraph content, i need to add a custom title before the next page content starts as you see in figure.

[image]

I know if we need to repeat same title , we can achieve it by using table and repeating header row. But there title will be same.  Here I need custom title.

Paragraph is getting populatated from backend  and how do we figure out page breaks happens at code level ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need this in the Word docx document, or is your ultimate output format something else eg PDF or HTML?  Word does insert a lastRenderedPageBreak tag, but this isn't much good to you since inserting content will make them meaningless.

Comment: I need this in a word document. basically i need to put a indication that what you read currently is continuation of last page paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

1. This has to do with the Word Object Model. Word really does not have the concept of pages in the underlying structure of a document. [Word Doesn't Know What a Page Is by Daiya Mitchell, MVP](https://wordmvp.com/Mac/PagesInWord.html)
2. Because of that, this would be better posted in the [Word Answers forum hosted by Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word).
3. There are ways to deal with this using headers (not table headers necessarily although they can be used) or using a shape anchored to the table to occlude the word "continued" in the original header.

When you say templating, are you talking about Word templates (term of art) or something else?

Comment: You should remove the meta commentary about your answer being a comment.  If you do not have the required permissions, to submit a comment, then you should not submit a comment as an answer.  Commentary submitted as an answer is typically deleted by the community.